# How do I create a csv file using Python from sybase db table depending on a value in a column of that table?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sybase

I am new at python and trying to write a script which connects with the database(Sybase ase) and copies the data present the table in the specific size of CSV files depending on one column in the table(index)

Code that I have tried:

```
server = 'XYZ' 
database = 'user_details' 
username = '' 
password = '' 
#have used sql express for now
import pyodbc
import csv
db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+'')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM userinfo")
list1 = c.fetchall()
#print (list1)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM userinfo;")
with open("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\out.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
 csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers
 csv_writer.writerows(cursor)
```

Now, I want to make CSV in batches. Like for eg. first 100 records of the table in 1 file(file_1.csv) and next 100 records in another file(file_2.csv). Depending on the output of the select statement.

How do I create a csv file using Python from sybase db table depending on a value in a column of that table?

Comment: in question show your code. If you get error then show full error message (starting at word "Traceback").

Comment: What does "size" refer to; number of rows, size of file on disk, something else?

Comment: size refers to rows